# How to add value in to multiple value field (entity reference)?

Tags: 7, entities

Im inserting into user field reference to other users. This is my code, but it is overiding all values of field, i just want too add value and keep values added before.

```
<?php 
global $user;

$user->field_profile_access['und'][]['target_id'] = 34;
user_save($user)


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line is wrong:

```
$user->field_profile_access['und'][]['target_id'] = 34;
```

You could try with:

```
$user->field_profile_access['und'][] = array('target_id' => 34);
```

or this:

```
$next = count($user->field_profile_access[LANGUAGE_NONE]);
$user->field_profile_access[LANGUAGE_NONE][$next]['target_id'] = 34;
```

I used `LANGUAGE_NONE` instead of `'und'` here, but that's not the problem.

Or even better, using the [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1842304). That example is for a field collection, but the idea should be useful for any entity, including nodes.

Comment: for more about the Entity API see https://www.drupal.org/node/1021556